# positioning divs in mosaic style

Tags: html, positioning, mosaic

I'm trying to build a website and am experiencing problems with the position of a div 'tile'. 
This is the site I'm working on :
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103417607/1/index.html
I'm fairly new to the CSS and responsive programming world. 
Problem I have is the 'date' tile on the right, when resizing the window, for some reason, this tile creeps up underneath the 'log on' tile. I just don't see what I'm doing wrong as I don't have this with the other tiles.

You can test it for yourself bij slowly dragging the right side of the browser window to the left (making the width smaller). The date tile will slowly creep up, while the other tiles (screenstar and latest news) stay nicely put. I don't understand this, as my css code is the same.

This is my CSS file : 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103417607/1/css/style.css

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is giving me headaches.

(I did check de JQUERY mosaic stuff, but I don't know if that is what I'm lookign for)

Thanks,
Maarten

Answer (score 0):

The `div` in question has the following CSS:

```
#datequote_position_front {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -610px;
}
```

Which tells us that the top edge of the `<div>` is *610px lower* than where it would normally be in the document flow.

We can safely assume the vertical position of the `<div>` is directly influenced by which other `<div>s` appear above it in the document flow.

The reason why the `<div>` is floating upward is because, as you reduce the width of the viewport, your horizontal menu disappears.

I haven't checked but I would guess the `<div>` is rising by a number of pixels exactly equivalent to the height of the horizontal menu.

Your solution to prevent the vertical position of the `<div>` from changing is, therefore, to use another method to position the `<div>` - ie. one that isn't relative to other elements in the document flow.

For instance:

```
#datequote_position_front {
    position: absolute;
    top: 610px;
    right: 6px;
}
```

This will mean that the `<div>` will always be absolutely positioned 610 pixels below the top edge of its parent and 6 pixels to the left of the right edge of its parent.

**N.B.**

Two points:

1) I haven't tested these styles in a browser so you may need to adjust the `top` and `right` co-ordinates of the `<div>` correctly according to your design.

2) You'll (probably) need to insert a `media query`, if you want to change the declared `absolute position` of the `<div>` at narrower viewport widths.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, do you have any idea why the other tiles to the left 'latest news' and 'screenstar" are not influenced by the removal of the menu?

Comment: I will experiment more with the absolute positioning, I just don't understand how I can solve it with a mediaquery as the tile move up pixel row per pixel. I don't understand why the other tiles, which also use the 'margin-top' statement, don't flow up ...

Comment: @ST Graveyard - As far as I can see, while the other `<div>s` are not exhibiting exactly the same behaviour, they are still jumping upward as well at the point when the horizontal menu disappears.

Comment: Yes, that I understand, but all the other tiles are going up the exact same distance as the menu above. While the problematic div also does this, it also starts moving up pixel by pixel for some reason. This I don't understand. I've been experimenting with absolute positioning, inline-block ... I just can't seem to figure it out. When you pick the right side of the browser window and you move slowly to the left (making it smaller) you'll see what I mean ...

Comment: There are several ways you can produce your intended responsive design flawlessly. One is to use a series of floats and clears (and change the declarations when the viewport becomes sufficiently narrow). The second is to absolutely position the header and the horizontal menu and the right-hand vertical column and then use floats and clears for the remaining `<div>s` on the left-hand 66% of the page. The third is to use the CSS3 flexbox module.

Comment: @ST Graveyard - yes, I see what you mean. I can't immediately pinpoint the root cause of that behaviour either. But see above for my 3 suggestions on how to approach producing your layout. I *wouldn't* use `position:relative` or `margin` to 2-dimensionally position the various divs - they simply don't give you enough control.

Comment: No problem, @STGraveyard! If you think they're worth a +1, I'd be most grateful - thanks!

Comment: I try to give you a vote, but it says 'vote up requires 15 reputartion' :-s ... I'm new here :::

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue thanks to these tips :
http://www.htmlforums.com/css/t-positioning-divs-in-mosaic-style-160801.html#post854724

Cheers.
Maarten